# Is the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian a constant of motion?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, curvature

In [QMechanic's Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2516784/1099433), it is stated that

> $L$ is a constant of motion (COM), and the constant of motion ≠0
> is not zero.

Is the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian a constant of motion? Does the square of its Lagrangian also give the same EOM?

Comment: What we mean by "time" in general relativity is surprisingly hard to pin down.  One of the fundamental precepts of GR is that we can define our coordinates however we like, and time is just one of our coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the source material. I have made edits and re-asked the question again.

Comment: No to both of those questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vacuum spacetimes Einstein–Hilbert Lagrangian being zero on solutions of Einstein equations is indeed a constant of motion. Because EH Lagrangian contains second derivatives of the metric, squaring it would lead to fourth order equations, so the answer to the second question is negative.